# Probability of winning a game similar to bingo

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was trying to do the following question:

[image]

I have attached the solutions and I am specifically confused about how they got the

$${20 \choose 2}$$

the numerator of the first part. I usually post what I have tried on a question like this but it seems hard to do that but I will try:

I saw that a line is of length 5 and thus realized that 25-5 = 20. So that means 20 is the remaining blocks from the game? However, I am not sure how the numerator came about...

I think I do understand that the denominator is all the ways to choose 7 balls from the 25 they give us, but the 20 and the 2 are remains a mystery to me...

Comment: the $\binom{20}{2}$ refers to the two numbers which were drawn which were not in the winning row/column/or diagonal.  Pick the winning line: 12 choices.  pick which 5 of the 5 numbers are in that row: $\binom{5}{5}=1$ choices,  pick which 2 numbers were also called that weren't in the winning line: $\binom{20}{2}$ choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given solution they have omitted a term that is equal to $1$ in the numerator and that is what caused confusion to you. The complete numerator is $$\dbinom{5}{5}\dbinom{25-5}{7-5}=\dbinom{5}{5}\dbinom{20}{2}=1\cdot\dbinom{20}{2}$$ where

1. The coefficient $\binom{5}{5}$ stands for choosing all $5$ elements of the given line. Of course this coefficient is equal to $1$ since there is a single way to do that. (This term is ommitted from the given solution).
2. The coefficient $\binom{25-5}{7-5}=\binom{25-5}{7-5}$ stands for choosing the remaining $7-5=2$ elements from the remaining $25-5=20$ elements.

Comment: is this question a "disguised" form of the hyper-geometric probability distribution?